# Code can't reverse the string. It prins empty

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, reverse

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    cout << "input";
    cin >> x;
    
    int y = x.size();
    
    string f;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= y-1; i++){
    
    f[i] = x[y-(1+i)];
    f[y] = '\0';
    
    }
    
    cout << f << endl;
    return 0;
    
}
```

As the code above shows, I am trying to reverse the string user's input.

`cin >> x;` stores the string input as `x`.

`int y = x.size();` gets the size of the string.

`f[i] = x[y-(1+i)];` reverses the string input.

Example:

```
Let the input be "hello",
So y=5.
f[0] = x[4] = o;
...
f[3] = x[1] = e;
f[4] = x[0] = h;
```

`cout << f << endl;` should print `f`.

BUT the code does not work.

I fear that it is because this:

```
f[i] = x[y-(1+i)];
f[y] = '\0';
```

is inside of keys `{}` and so does not change the value of `f`. Is that the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: The code has **undefined behavior** because it is accessing characters past the end of the string.  And that's bad, mm-kay?

Comment: If you have never used vectors before in c++ I would recommend them. The c-style arrays are always a pain in the

Comment: `string f;` creates a string of length exactly 0. Then you start accessing things at positions other than zero in that string. If I give you a bucket containing zero apples and ask you to pick out an apple, what happens?

Comment: `f[i] = x[y-(1+i)];` Change that to this: `f.at(i) = x.at(y-(1+i));`.  You will then see the error as an exception `std::out_of_range.`, and explains what others have mentioned.

Comment: why the downvotes people. This is a perfect example of a good SO question. We know why it fails but the questioner does not, that not a reason to downvote

Comment: Thank you all. @SilvioMayolo Thank you. I didn't know string f creates a string of length 0, i thought it create a string with indefined length. 

Funny enough, i just edited and wrote a line after "string f": 

f = x

to fixe the f size, and now it works haha.

Comment: @pm100 Completely agree. Sometimes people get a little trigger-happy with the downvote button. Perhaps we can help rectify that :P

Comment: @LSS "*I didn't know string f creates a string of length 0, i thought it create a string with indefined length.*" - the string is initially empty but can reach an indefinite length. The problem is that you are simply not adding any characters to it.

Answer (score 3):

To create a reversed copy of the source string you could just write

```
string f( x.rbegin(), x.rend() );
```

If to use the approach with the for loop then the loop can look the following way

```
for ( auto n = x.size(), i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    f += x[n - i - 1];
}
```

Before the for loop you could reserve required memory for the string f like

```
f.reserve( x.size() );
```

As for your code then at least you may not use the subscript operator with the empty string `f`. And there is no need to add explicitly the terminating zero character '`\0'`.

Moreover if before the for loop you will write

```
string f(y,' ');
```

as it was advised nevertheless this statement

```
f[y] = '\0';
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this out**

Simply loop through the string the user provide and start taking the character from the last index value minus one(-1) to the first index value and append it to the variable f

**For Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    cout << "digite algo\n";
    cin >> x;
    
    int y = x.size();
    
    string f;
    
    for (int i = y-1; i>=0; i--){
    
    f+= x.at(i);
    
    }
    
    cout << f << endl;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Rather than give an answer with no explanation, please show what's wrong with the OP's code.  Better to give them a little bit to learn rather than entire code which they don't have to learn from.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I have added explaination I was a bit busy that why I didn't do that at first but anyway thanks for the alert!

Answer (score 1):

to use the same logic as you have you need

```
string f = x;
```

or

```
string f(y,' ');
```

to allocate f large enough to hold the resulting string